# The displayed bonded amount is lower than the bonded amount itself in the targets

Tags: staking, validator

I'm encountering an issue with staking. When I bond an amount of 100, the explorer displays 92 in the targets, but the account section shows the entire amount.

For the example the validator present in the storage has bonded 100

[image]

But in the target section, the validator displays the own stake is 92
[image]